# ASP.Net MVC 5 Entity Framework Select Where In?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I have 3 tables Project, Province, ProjProvRel

In my project page when I add data I select multiple provinces for each project
means my Province is multi select dropdown list.

I insert data it is working I get the inserted Id and added to ProjProvRel with selected Ids of Province

Now In details view I want to display my data but I could not solve it.

here is my code:

```
    // GET: Project/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        var mydata = db.Projects.Find(id);
        if (mydata == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var prov_id =  from o in db.ProRel where o.ProjectId.Equals(id) select o.ProvinceIds;
        foreach (var p_id in prov_id)
        {
            int[] PIds = new int[] {p_id};
        }
        var Prov= from c in db.Provinces where c.ID in pIds;
        ViewBag.Province = Prov;
        return View(mydata);
    }
```

one problem is how can I select data from table based on where condition

```
var prov_id =  from o in db.ProRel where o.ProjectId.Equals(id) select o.ProvinceIds;
```

is the above query correct ? I am new to ASP.Net MVC
also blow query is correct ?

```
var Prov= from c in db.Provinces where c.ID in pIds;
```

how can I select data from Table Province where province.ID in PIds

Comment: `int[] PIds = p_id;` is just initializing a new value for `PIds` in each loop (your not appending the values)

Answer (score 2):

Get the rows from ProRel where the ProjectId matches with id:

```
var prov_ids = db.ProRel.Where(r => r.ProjectId == id).Select(r => r.ProvinceId);
```

Get the provinces that can be found from prov_id:

```
var provs = db.Provinces.Where(p => prov_id.Any(i => p.ID == i));
```

I hope you don't mind the lambda-style LINQ.

Also, I think you should consider your variable naming. For example, prov_id gives the idea of a single id and since you declared the type implicitly it is difficult to tell otherwise.